# jQuery live() and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, live

I have select inputs dynamically added to form by

```
$(selector).append(html)
```

I'm using `live('change',handler)` to bind change event for all selects. The problem is that code is fine in all browser, except Internet Explorer (all versions).

I've replaced live() with the plugin `livequery()` still working in all browser and i have strange behaviors in Internet Explorer.

Could someone tell me the right way to bind events to elements that will be created after page has finished loading?

And if you know some good debugging tool for tracking Ajax requests (Internet Explorer).

Thans. Microsoft for makes life harder.

Comment: For tracking Ajax you might want to try my new jQuery plug-in ajaxMonitor @: http://github.com/gutzofter/ajaxMonitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you're still using a pre-1.4.2 release of jQuery, if you upgrade to the [jQuery1.4.2 release](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/) your problems should go away.

1.4.2 included an events module re-write that resolved [the `change` bubbling issue in IE](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5851).

Comment: sure i'm using  jQuery1.4.2 release 
maybe  the error is in my code , i cant post it here because so long 
but this is the part that need some tweak :

jQuery("#filtres").live("change",handler);

handler is a function that request server via $.ajax 
and append the result(html)  to  div content

thanx